# Voice controlled robot using Arduino

Tags: arduino

I have to use an Android device to control an Arduino Uno through a Bleutooth module.
The program is working, but I have one problem.

How can I make the code for each command repeated many times?
For example, I want to repeat "walk" command, until I give the command "stop"?
When I give the command "walk" it will keep walking.

This is the code:

```cpp
#include <Servo.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial blue(4, 3); //TX, RX  pins of arduino respetively

String command;
Servo myservo1;
Servo myservo2;
Servo myservo3;
Servo myservo4;

void setup()
{
    blue.begin(9600);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Ready");

    myservo1.attach(9, 600, 2300); // (pin, min, max)
    myservo2.attach(10, 600, 2300);
    myservo3.attach(11, 600, 2300);
    myservo4.attach(12, 600, 2300);

    myservo1.write(30); //right leg            (0 point)
    myservo2.write(170); //lift leg             (0 point)
    myservo3.write(170); //left hand               (0)
    myservo4.write(30); //right hand             (0)
}
void loop()
{
    while (blue.available()) { //Check if there is an available byte to read
        delay(10); //Delay added to make thing stable
        char c = blue.read(); //Conduct a serial read
        command += c; //build the string.
    }
    if (command.length() > 0) {
        Serial.println(command);

        if (command == "walk") {
            myservo1.write(30);
            myservo2.write(160);
            myservo4.write(100);
            delay(1000);
            myservo4.write(30);
            delay(1000);
            myservo1.write(40);
            myservo2.write(170);
            myservo3.write(100);
            delay(1000);
            myservo3.write(170);
            delay(1000);
        }
        if (command == "raise your hands") {
            myservo4.write(180);
            myservo3.write(20);
        }
        if (command == "raise your left hand") {
            myservo3.write(20);
            delay(2000);
            myservo3.write(170);
            delay(1000);
        }
        if (command == "raise your right hand") {
            myservo4.write(180);
            delay(2000);
            myservo4.write(30);
            delay(1000);
        }
        if (command == "stop") {
            myservo1.write(30);
            myservo2.write(170);
            myservo3.write(170);
            myservo4.write(30);
        }

        command = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: remove `command="";`?

Comment: am already try with that.

Comment: but the problem that it will not take other command